# unable to get child nodes' names of a parent node having name="debitRequest" in xml file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

i am using xml file "SavedWSDL.txt" some of the part of it is given below...

```
  ...
<wsdl:message name="LookUpTransactionResponse">
<wsdl:part name="LookUpTransactionReturn" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_anyType"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="LookUpTransactionRequest"></wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="creditResponse">
<wsdl:part name="creditReturn" type="xsd:int"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="creditRequest">
<wsdl:part name="amount" type="xsd:float"/>
<wsdl:part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="debitRequest">
<wsdl:part name="amount" type="xsd:float"/>
<wsdl:part name="password" type="xsd:string"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="debitResponse">
<wsdl:part name="debitReturn" type="xsd:int"/>
</wsdl:message>
    ...
```

i have written java code given below, WHAT SHOULD BE used to get child node names of wsdl:message tag named as "debitRequest"

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Ex2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse("D:/SavedWSDL.txt");
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("wsdl:message");
            //System.out.println("No. of Nodes: "+nodelist.getLength());

            for(int i=0;i<nodelist.getLength();i++){
                Node node=nodelist.item(i);
                String valueOfTag=node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
                if(valueOfTag.equalsIgnoreCase("debitrequest")){
                    if(node.hasChildNodes()){
                        NodeList childNList=node.getChildNodes();
                        //System.out.println("No. of Childs: "+node.getChildNodes().getLength());
                        //System.out.println(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("NO CHILD FOUND for: "+valueOfTag);
                    }
                }   
            }
        } catch(Exception io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you attempt to get debtrequest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your given XML there is Text (invisible) between the Nodes:

```
<wsdl:message name="debitRequest"> <-- Text
<wsdl:part name="amount" type="xsd:float"/> <-- Text
<wsdl:part name="password" type="xsd:string"/> <-- Text
</wsdl:message>
```

This is why your Node with the name `debitRequest` has 5 Childs (Text, Node, Text, Node, Text)

The NodeType of a new ChildNode is 1, and the NodeType of Text is 3:

`node.getNodeType() //1 is ChildNode, 3 is Text`

So after you have your node and you want to get all its childs you should loop it and check for the type. Then you can check for the Attributes.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Ex2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse("testxml.xml");
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("wsdl:message");
            //System.out.println("No. of Nodes: "+nodelist.getLength());

            for(int i=0;i<nodelist.getLength();i++){
                Node node=nodelist.item(i);
                String valueOfTag=node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
                if(valueOfTag.equalsIgnoreCase("debitrequest")){
                    if(node.hasChildNodes()){
                        NodeList childNList=node.getChildNodes();
                        for(int j = 0; j < childNList.getLength();j++)
                        {
                            Node n = childNList.item(j);
                            if(n.getNodeType() == 1) //NodeType 1 = Next XML Node
                            {
                                String nvalue = n.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
                                System.out.println(nvalue);
                            }
                            /*if(n.getAttributes() != null){
                                String s = n.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
                                System.out.println(s);
                            }*/
                        }
                        System.out.println(childNList.getLength());

                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("NO CHILD FOUND for: "+valueOfTag);
                    }
                }   
            }
        } catch(Exception io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    }
```

You could also loop your childs and get check for every `Node.getAttributes()` if it is null. If it isn't you can search for the `"name"` in Attribute and continue. This second way is also shown in my code, but commented out. Its the: `if(n.getAttributes() != null){` Comment.

Comment: thanks a lot to you there for ur gr8 support.. my problem is solved

Comment: user name: @Loki how u know that the TEXT tag is invisible ..?

Comment: Well not invisible, but you dont have Text between your XML-Nodes. So its just a Blank Text --> `""`. 


If you have your Node and look at `childNList.getLength()` which returns 5 but your XML-Code only has 2 Childs you should have assumed there are some more "childs". 

If you Print out the `n.getNodeName()` for every Child for your Text it returns `#Text`.

So you can be sure there are some more Childs which only are Text. But because you haven't set any Text to your XML its just Blank Text